# Content Type and Content Length are set but $_POST array is empty

Tags: php, linux

I have a fairly fresh apache/php install on a local server running php 5.3.8 and Zend Engine 2.3.0 with eAccelerator, Xdebug, and Suhosin. Everything is good except for a major post issue. Every time a form is submitted as post, no data comes through. (print_r($_POST) returns a blank array.)

I have also done a print_r on $_SERVER and notice that the content_type is set correctly to application/x-www-form-urlencoded and the content_length is set appropriately and even varies based on the length of information that is entered in the form before submission.

That being said all of the following code returns nothing:

```
var_dump($_POST);

$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
var_dump($data);
```

Having read everything I could find through other questions, I have checked a variety of php.ini settings and looked through the phpinfo() list and all post related variables seem to be set properly and more than large enough to at the very least handle a form with two text input boxes...

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without further information, I can only give some very generic instructions:

1. Verify the values of the `action` and `method` attributes that your form element has, or otherwise ensure it's doing what you expect. (Both method and action attributes are important.)
2. Ensure you have a connection to the web server, and that no application firewall is filtering the POST request, including both hardware and software.
3. Ensure that your request is well formed by intercepting it with wireshark on your local network or computer. Use wireshark and other tools to track down where the request is going and ensure it is arriving.
4. Log onto your server and review the it's logs. Ensure that you are receiving the request. If not, check for a local application firewall or some other tool (like mod_security) intercepting the request. If so, review the pre- and post- processed request from the server's perspective. Ensure the target coincides with the value of `action` in step 1.
5. Guess at random or ask your (or a) systems administrator.

Comment: Thank you. I had pretty much already moved to step 5, but I was afraid that I had missed something fairly obvious. I have been testing with a form that correctly redirects to a different page just without POST info. If I change the method from post to get, the information can be retrieved from $_GET or $_REQUEST. I just now downloaded wireshark and can see a perfectly formed POST request to the server. I'm guessing that there is some extra tool installed and will test some more on that later today. Thank you for your response!